# How to find the area of a complex polygon - c++

Tags: c++, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

For non-complex polygons, it's pretty simple:

```
A = 1/2 * (x1*y2 - x2*y1 + x2*y3 - x3*y2 + ... + x(n-1)*yn - xn*y(n-1) + xn*y1 - x1*yn)
```

Here is my implementation in C++:

```
struct Point { 
    double x, y;
} point[210];

double area(int n) {
    double a=0, b=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n-1; ++i) {
        a += point[i].x * point[i+1].y;
        b += point[i].y * point[i+1].x;
    }
    return (a - b)/2;
}
```

But what if the polygon is complex? Is there a similar way of finding it's area?

**Note:** I tried to use the same technique, but it didn't work. For the polygon

```
(0,0) , (0,7) , (4,3) , (0,3) , (2,4) , (2,1) , (0, 0)
```

the formula above gives me 28.000, which should be 26.000. The only explanation I could give was that the triangle (0,3) , (2,4) , (2,3) is counted twice(the point (2,3) is the intersection of the segments (0,3) , (4,3) and (2,4) , (2,1)).

Comment: The formula you're using is for non-self-intersecting polygons but you have an intersection for lines (4,3)-(0,3) and (2,4)-(2,1). For self-interecting polygons you need to make a [decision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Self-intersecting_polygons) of how to treat the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](http://www.mathwords.com/a/area_convex_polygon.htm) the formula you have illustrated is **for convex polygons**, but the example you give **does not appear to be** one.

p.s. Instead of a 2D array, consider using the below for better readability.

```
struct Point{ 
   double x,y;
};

Point point[210];

...
a += point[i].x * point[i+1].y;
```

Comment: according to this: http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/area-irregular-polygons.html the formula can also work for non-convex polygons.

Answer (score 0):

That formula works for *simple* polygons (those how are not *self-intersecting*), convex or not. Note that it computes the *signed* area of the polygon. If the (simple) polygon is *oriented clockwise*, the area computed using that formula will be negative.

For a non-simple polygon, the formula computes the sum of signed area of all the simple components of the polygon. Your example component has self-intersections, and indeed one components of it, the triangle, contributes twice to the area.